# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [javax.mail.Session] is not an allowed property value type

Tags: java, email, build, jndi

I'm getting this message when I start up my spring webapp in Glassfish 7.0.3. All the googling I find tells me to delete mail.jar from WEB-INF/lib but it isn't in there. I find the following jars containing "Session":

```
./glassfish/modules/angus-mail.jar
./glassfish/modules/jakarta.mail-api.jar
./glassfish/modules/mail-connector.jar
./glassfish/modules/mail-runtime.jar
```

Should I be changing to jakarta.mail ?